# Can one website be accessed via multiple domains with ssl?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

Can a website on a vps with a dedicated ip be accessed via multiple domain names and use ssl where needed? How would this be done on IIS 7.5 WIndows R2 2008

Comment: you'll need one SSL certificate per IP:PORT pair

Answer (score 3):

Re: your first question:

Sure, a website can be accessed via multiple domain names using SSL.  In most instances this means you'll need multiple SSL certificates, but it will work just fine.  If all the domain name share a common parent domain, you may be able simplify things with a wildcard certificate (although those are typically more expensive).

Re: your second question:

Haven't the foggiest.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do so, using TLS (SSLv3) Server Name Indication (SNI). This is not supported in every browser, but it's much better than it was two years ago.

TLS-SNI is not officially supported in IIS7.5, so no it can't be done in IIS7.5.

Though it looks like you can complain to Microsoft about it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/533553/add-support-in-iis-for-sni).